# Dual properties of regular maps - injectivity and surjectivity.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory

Let $X \subseteq k^n, Y \subseteq k^m$ be algebraic varieties. Suppose we have a regular map, $\phi:X \rightarrow Y$ induced from a polynomial.  $\phi$ induces a $k$-algebra homomorphism on the coordinate rings,

$$ \phi' : A(Y) \rightarrow A(X), \quad [\eta] \mapsto [\eta \circ \phi ] $$

Where $A(K):= k[x_1, \ldots, x_t]/I(K)$. for an algebraic set $K \subseteq k^t$.

---

I noticed that if $\phi$ is surjective, then $\phi'$ is injective. Is the converse true?

> If $\phi'$ is injective then is $\phi$ surjective?

---

My thoughts: If statement were true. Prove contrapositive. Then there must exists two maps $f,g \in k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ such that

(i) $f(y) \not= g(y)$ (this implies $[f]\not= [g]$ in $A(Y)$)

(ii) $f(\phi(X)) = g(\phi(X))$.

This does not seem plausible in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not imply that it is surjective. For example, the map $A^1 \setminus {0} \to A^1$ by inclusion induces an injection on the coordinate rings. This is because any polynomial is determined by its restriction to $A^1 \setminus 0$.

What is true is that $\phi$ is dominant; i.e. the image is dense. (To prove this, consider the closure of the image. If the image is not dense, then the closure is a proper subvariety. In particular, there is a nonzero polynomial $f$ that is zero on $\overline{im(\phi)}$, and $f$ must be in the kernel of the pullback map.)

Comment: Thanks, but sorry, I do not know much algebraic geometry notation, what is $A^1$ - where can I get further reference on $\phI$ being dominant? Btw: $\phi$ surjective $\Rightarrow $ $\phi'$ is injective is true right (?).

Comment: @CWL Shaferevich's algebraic geometry book one will treat all of this. Then if you want to learn the 'modern' language Ravi Vakils notes are good. (But start with Shaferevich.) A^1 is k, the line. It's preferable to write it that way because k has a distinguished point (0). Yes, surjective maps are dominant.

Comment: And dominant maps induce injections on the coordinate ring. (Since they have dense image, they can distinguish functions. You think about the case of, for example, any two continuous real valued function on the real line are determined by their values on the rationals...)